# trace and log commands executed in a k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-security

I want to log all commands and subcommands executed in a k8s pod. This is possible, for example with auditbeat, on virtual machines. But I didn't find any useful tool or solution for k8s pods.
I want to log all commands, for example if someone executes bash and then executes ifconfig, I want to log them both.
Anyone have any ideas?

I found Falco for this purpose but I don't think it can solve my problem completely.

Comment: Check out [tetragon](https://github.com/cilium/tetragon)

Comment: Thnak you @Chris. Is there any way to get k8s user that executed commands in a pod?